# update data to database laragon using api

Tags: laravel, ionic3

I want to update data to the database in ionic. how to make the data update. Here what I tried. I try using postmen to post the api and it appear success but the data does not change.

in api.php

```
public function update (Request $request)
    {      
            $id = $request->id;
            $medname = $request->medname;
            $price = $request->price;
            $stock = $request->stock;
            $medno = $request->medno;
            $ingredient = $request->ingredient;
            $description = $request->description;
            $addinfo = $request->addinfo;


            AddMedicine:: where('medname',$medname)->update([

                'id' =>$id,
                'medname'=>$medname,
                'price'=>$price,
                'stock'=>$stock,
                'medno'=>$medno,
                'ingredient'=>$ingredient,
                'description'=>$description,
                'addinfo'=>$addinfo,
            ]);
                $msg = "Data Updated"; 
                $datamsg = response()->json([
                    'success' => $msg   
                ]);
                return $datamsg->content();

    }
```

route

```
Route::put('/update','ApiController@update');
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure use PUT request ? Because need to CSRF token please inspect

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30756682/laravel-x-csrf-token-mismatch-with-postman
```

Comment: then should I use post method then?

Comment: Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php 

protected $except = [
        'update',
    ]; you can update verifycsrf your route.

Comment: thank you for your response @SafakCiplak. Can I know where to apply the code?

Comment: I share previous comment

Comment: Can you success?

Comment: yes I do success. thank you for your response. I just change the function to POST and add the id when posting the data.