# Vue cant get CSRF token from laravel blade

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, csrf

I have a blade that have this code.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<covid-form>
 </covid-form>
```

Then in my covid-form component i got a form like this:

```
  <form @submit.prevent="send">
 <input type="hidden" name="_token" :value="csrf">
```

My component script.

```
<script>
    export default {
        data(){

            return{
                csrf: document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content,
                fullname:'',
                phone:'',
                nationality:'',
                have_not_travelled_to_china:false,
                have_not_travelled_to_others:false,
                have_not_travelled_to_asian:false,
                no_issue_to_stay_home:false,
                no_symptomps:false,
                dont_have_close_contact:false,

                signDate:new Date(),
                    opts:{
                        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                        showClear: true,
                        showClose: true,
                        useCurrent: false,
                    },
                date: new Date(),
                    opt:{
                        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm A',
                        showClear: true,
                        showClose: true,
                        useCurrent: false,
                    }

            }
        },
       created(){
           console.log(this.csrf)
       },
        methods:{
           async send(){
                   let loader = this.$loading.show({
                            container: this.fullPage ? null : this.$refs.formContainer,
                            onCancel: this.onCancel,
                            color: '#c91010',
                            loader: 'bars',
                            width: 80,
                            height: 100,
                })
               await axios.post('/submitForm',{
                    agent_name: this.fullname,
                    phone: this.phone,
                    nationality: this.nationality,
                    have_not_travelled_to_china: this.have_not_travelled_to_china,
                    have_not_travelled_to_others: this.have_not_travelled_to_others,
                    have_not_travelled_to_asian: this.have_not_travelled_to_asian,
                    no_issue_to_stay_home: this.no_issue_to_stay_home,
                    no_symptomps: this.no_symptomps,
                    dont_have_close_contact: this.dont_have_close_contact,
                    signDate: this.signDate,
                    date: this.date
                })
                    .then(()=>{
                         swal.fire({
                            title: 'Success!',
                            icon: 'success',
                            width: '500px'
                        });
                        loader.hide() 
                    })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

UPDATE:
I dont have any errors in console. Tried it in postman with `127.0.0.1:8000/submitForm` with post request. But everytime i submit i got `"message": "CSRF token mismatch.",` . Also i removed the @csrf in my blade because it is already in the header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the `_token` property to the axios data like you are doing with the others:

```
await axios.post('/submitForm',{
  _token: this.csrf,
  agent_name: this.fullname,
  // ...
})
```

this is required for `post` requests.

And since you will set the data to axios, from the data function

```
data() {
  return{
    csrf: document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content,
    agent_name: this.fullname,
    //...
  },
},
```

You can remove this line

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" :value="csrf">
```

you are not using it at all.

Also you will need to set `X-Requested-With` headers to axios request, 
but probably you already have somenthing like [this](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/c4a7a7bc9cdccd00d6fdda8846d1660a0608d7ef/resources/js/bootstrap.js#L24).

> The `VerifyCsrfToken` [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/middleware), which is included in the `web` middleware group, will automatically verify that the token in the request input matches the token stored in the session.

You can read more on the docs:
[CSRF Protection](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/csrf)

Comment: I updated the answer. you are missing adding the token to the data you send by axios

Comment: why do i got `CSRF token mismatched` in postman when i add `Accept: application/json`. But when i dont add it i got `Page Exlpired`

Comment: [CSRF Protection](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/csrf) The routes that are inside the `web` middleware expects some headers with session information, but in postman you doesn't have that information, so Page Expired comes up because your csrf token verification fails. You can read about use postman with laravel web middleware [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30756682/laravel-x-csrf-token-mismatch-with-postman). CSRF token mismatched probably because the _token input is missing, wich is required for post requests.

Comment: okay i see. thats why it always says like that. Thanks for the answer sir :)