# Laravel 8, Sanctum, Fortify /logout throws "CSRF token mismatch" in Postman

Tags: php, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum, laravel-fortify

I installed L8, Sanctum, and Fortify for authentication. I was able to `/login` (used a `Pre-request Script` to set the `X-XSRF-TOKEN`). I even get the `/api/user` successfully. But when I do `/logout`, I get "CSRF Token Mismatch" error in Postman. My settings in files are as below:

**.env**

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:8000
```

**cors.php**

```
'paths' => ['api/*', 'login', 'logout', 'register', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie']
```

**fortify.php**

```
'views' => false
```

**/app/Http/Kernel.php**

```
'api' => [
  \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
  'throttle:api',
  \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
],
```

I haven't used `HasApiTokens` trait in `User` model since this is cookie-based authentication.

In Postman, I am using the below headers for the `/logout` route:

```
Accept:application/json
Referer:localhost:8000
X-XSRF-TOKEN:{{xsrf-token}}
```

and I am making a `POST` request to `http://localhost:8000/logout`. Why I am getting "CSRF Token Mismatch" error?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you ever solved this, but if not I've just had to solve the very same issue.

The reason it's failing is because the CSRF token is updated for each request so you need to add post-request script to your login request (and any other requests you make).

e.g. you can add a script to the Tests section of the request:

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("xsrf-token", postman.getResponseCookie("XSRF-TOKEN").value);
tests["CSRF token updated"] = true;
```

The second line is there to ensure the script doesn't report a fail every time.

I also found that it might be necessary to use `decodeURIComponent()` on the token value.

Answer (score 1):

In your `App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken` middleware, add `/api/logout` to the `$except` array:

```
protected $except = [
    '/api/logout'
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Vendor packages also use the `.env` (`SESSION_DOMAIN` and `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS`), so sometimes there is weird behavior.

Remove these from the `.env` if present

```
# SESSION_DOMAIN=
# SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=
```

Add these to the `.env`. Make sure the URL is in full (scheme, domain and port (when in development))

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000

FRONTEND_URLS=http://localhost:5173,http://localhost:5174,http://localhost:5175,http://localhost:5176
```

Add these to `config/cors.php`

```php
return [
    'paths' => ['*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => explode(',', env('FRONTEND_URLS')),

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,
]
```

Add these to `config/sanctum.php`

```php
return [
...
'stateful' => explode(
        ',',
        env(
            'SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS',
            sprintf(
                '%s%s%s',
                'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
                env('APP_URL') ? ',' . parse_url(env('APP_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : '',
                env('FRONTEND_URLS')
                    ? implode(
                        ',',
                        array_map(function ($url) {
                            return parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
                        }, explode(',', env('FRONTEND_URLS')))
                    )
                    : ''
            )
        )
    ),
...
]
```

Make sure this line is present in `kernel.php`

```php
 protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            ...
        ],

        'api' => [
            \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class, // <---
          ...
        ],
    ];
```

Then don't forget to clear the cache both in development and server.

```bash
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```